# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, typeerror

I am solving a problem with genetic algorithm in python 3. I have not completed the full code yet. I test a part of the code whenever I complete it.

At present, I am stuck with an error saying:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'part' and 'part'

The interesting thing is, this error does not always show. Sometimes the code runs smoothly and show the desired output, but sometimes it shows this error.

What is the reason for this?

I am attaching the code and the error message.
I am using PyCharm.

```
import random


class part():
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
        self.machine_sequence = []

    def add_volume(self, volume):
        self.volume = volume

    def add_machine(self, machine_numbers):
        self.machine_sequence.append(machine_numbers)


def create_initial_population():
    part_family = []

    for i in range(8):
        part_family.append(part(i))

    part_population = []

    for i in range(6):
        part_population.append(random.sample(part_family, len(part_family)))

    for i in part_population:
        for j in i:
            j.add_volume(random.randrange(100, 200))

    return part_population


def fitness(part_family):
    sum_of_boundary = []
    for i in range(0, 8, 2):
        sum_of_boundary.append(sum(j.volume for j in part_family[i:i + 2]))

    fitness_value = 0

    for i in range(len(sum_of_boundary) - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(sum_of_boundary)):
            fitness_value = fitness_value + abs(sum_of_boundary[i] - sum_of_boundary[j])

    return fitness_value


def sort_population_by_fitness(population):
    pre_sorted = [[fitness(x),x] for x in population]
    sort = [x[1] for x in sorted(pre_sorted)]
    for i in sort:
        for j in i:
            print(j.volume, end = ' ')
        print()

    return sort


def evolve(population):
    population = sort_population_by_fitness(population)
    return population


population = create_initial_population()
population = evolve(population)
```

the error message:
[image]

The Output is (which is randomized every time):
[image]

Comment: Can I suggest you download and use [a command prompt which allows copying](https://conemu.github.io/) so you don't need to add unnecessary screenshots to your questions.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Given that `pre_sorted` is a list of lists with items `[fitness, part]`, this croaks whenever comparing two sublists with the same `fitness`.

Python lists sort lexicographically and are compared element-wise left to right until a mismatching element is found. In your case, the second element (`part`) is only accessed if the fitness of two parts is the same.

- `[0, part0] < [1, part1]` => does not compare `part0` and `part1` since the fitness is already different.
- `[0, part0] < [0, part1]` => **does** compare `part0` and `part1` since the fitness is the same.

#### Suggestion 1

Sort only by fitness: `sorted(pre_sorted, key=operator.itemgetter(0))`

#### Suggestion 2

Read the documentation for [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) give `part` a total order:

```
@total_ordering
class part():
    [...]

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.number < other.number
```

And yeah, sorting lists of lists seems wrong. The inner elements might better be tuples, so you cannot accidentally modify the contents.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!
But when I use operator.itemgetter(0) to compare only the first element fitness, then what python do if there is same fitness? Which element it selects ?

Comment: @Zaidur `sort()` is stable, i.e. for two elements that compare the same, the original order is preserved. But note that you just created a population using random sampling just before.

Comment: Thank you so much too!! I was using `pandas.Multiindex` packed with  SQLAlchemy's `Base` child classes then applying a `pandas.Series.groupby` was raising the exception. Of course I applied the decorator to only my parent class and implemented only the "<" overload. BTW, this only became an issue after upgrading pandas 1.4.2 to 1.5.2 under Ananconda Python 3.9.16.

Answer (score 5):

So `pre_sorted` is a list with elements of `[int, part]`. When you sort this list and have two elements with the same integer value, it then compares the `part` values to try to determine which goes first. However, since you have no function for determining if a part is less than a part, it throws that error.

Try adding a function `__lt__(self, other)` to be able to order parts.

[More on operators here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/operator.html)