# Python "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of" when sorting two lists together

Tags: python, sorting

I have two lists

```
list_of_floats = [list of floats]
list_of_stuff = [list of custom class objects]
```

where `custom class objects` is an arbitrary class. The two lists have the same length and I want to sort `list_of_stuff` in terms of `list_of_floats`. So I proceeded as usual in Python

```
sorted_stuff = [x for _,x in sorted(zip(list_of_floats,list_of_stuff))]
```

Depending on the content of `list_of_stuff` sometimes this works and sometimes this raises `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'stuff' and 'stuff'`. When I say "depending on the content" what I change is the "value" of the instances, but not the type of objects in `list_of_stuff`.

I don't understand why is it trying to compare two objects of the arbitrary class between themselves, because it is sorting in terms of the objects (floats) in `list_of_floats`. In fact `list_of_stuff` could be populated with objects of different classes...

I tried to reproduce my error with a simple code but was not able. The objects in my `list_of_stuff` are quite complicated. However I think that the content of `list_of_stuff` should be irrelevant for this question.

Comment: both examples uses numbers. None of them is using `InvertersSequence`

Comment: I'm sure you could make a much more concise example that gives the same error.. you are more likely to get good answers if people don't have to decipher reams of irrelevant code. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: '<' not supported between instances Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477958/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-python)

Comment: Both your examples work on my machine

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. I bet you could produce the same error with only 5-10 lines of code.

Comment: @balderman the objects in ```list_of_stuff``` are of the class ```TDCInvertersSequenceAndCounter``` but when printed they look like floats. But they are not. I just realized about this, sorry.

Comment: @JeffUK @Peter Wood I tried to reproduce my problem with a simpler ```Stuff``` class but I was not able until now. However, I think that the content in the ```list_of_stuff``` should be irrelevant.

Comment: @TrebledJ Thanks for your suggestion. I read that question before asking this one. It did not solved my case unfortunately.

Comment: If two of your floats are equal, Python is going to look at the second element of your tuples (the custom class objects) in order to break the tie.  Either implement `.__lt__()` on the custom class (to make the objects comparable), or use `zip(list_of_floats, range(len(list_of_floats), list_of_stuff)` to guarantee that all tuples are unique without having to compare the custom objects.

Comment: @jasonharper it was that! I forgot to consider that even though it is not very likely, two floats can be equal, and I did not knew that in that case Python would compare the elements of the second list. Please upgrade your comment to an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credit of this answer goes to @jasonharper. He said in a comment:

If two of your floats are equal, Python is going to look at the second element of your tuples (the custom class objects) in order to break the tie. Either implement `.__lt__()` on the custom class (to make the objects comparable), or use `zip(list_of_floats, range(len(list_of_floats), list_of_stuff)` to guarantee that all tuples are unique without having to compare the custom objects.

I solved my problem using `zip(list_of_floats, range(len(list_of_floats), list_of_stuff)`.