# Is there a way to make a priority queue sort by the priority value in a tuple only, ignoring the other value in a pair?

Tags: python, priority-queue

I am using Python's `Queue.PriorityQueue` (in an implementation of the A* algorithm, though I'm not sure if this is relevant). I'm using it to hold objects that are non-comparable (an object class provided by a professor that I cannot modify), and Python throws an error when it tries to add an priority-object tuple (ex. `pq.put(1, object)`) when it's already holding a tuple with the same priority.

This is the relevant part of the error:

```
File "pathfinding.py", line 192, in astar
  frontier.put((priority, neighbor))
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/queue.py", line 149, in put
  self._put(item)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/queue.py", line 233, in _put
  heappush(self.queue, item)
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'InfNode' and 'InfNode'
```

Basically, I am looking for a way to bypass the PriorityQueue trying to compare these two objects. The exact order in which objects of the same priority are sorted is completely unimportant to me.

I did find [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477958/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-python), but it doesn't use a PriorityQueue, so I'm not sure if I can do something similar, or if this isn't possible altogether (in which case I'll have to modify my algorithm to be whatever this is, which is not preferable.).

Comment: `queue.PriorityQueue` is a terrible choice for that, by the way - it's designed to be an inter-thread message passing system, not a general-purpose heap. Also, it doesn't support decrease-key, which is important for a good A* implementation.

Comment: Also, "I did find this solution, but it doesn't use a PriorityQueue" - it does! What are you talking about?

Comment: What's wrong with the documentation's suggestion starting with *"If the data elements are not comparable"*?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Ah, if that case, what data structure do you think I should use instead? Like I said before, I really don't know anything about python.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica oh oops I linked the wrong answer! Sorry about that. I'll get that fixed

Comment: @superbrain ah, for some reason I hadn't seen that all when i was trying to find an answer for this! Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @pentodell: `heapq` is somewhat more appropriate, but doesn't have decrease-key support either. I'd go with a custom heap implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, just in case someone ends up here, I ended up taking superb rain's comment into consideration since I was looking for a simpler solution, and I didn't really have time to overhaul my solution to make it more efficient or better. I just needed something to work.

The solution was basically just implement the suggestion [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/queue.html). If there's anyone that's looking at this that just really doesn't understand how Python works (like me!), stick this at the top.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Any

@dataclass(order=True)
class PrioritizedItem:
    priority: int
    item: Any=field(compare=False)
```

And then instead of using `.put()` with a tuple, put the entire PrioritizedItem class in instead `pq.put(PrioritizedItem(0, start))` or `pq.put(PrioritizedItem(priority, data))`. And then to get the item out: `current = pq.get().item`.

I would like to acknowledge user2357112-supports-Monica's suggestion to go with a custom heap implementation. If I had time or any real knowledge of how to use Python, I would have liked to have tried it, but again I didn't really have time for more than a bare-minimum-functional solution.

And I'm only posting this here for propriety. This solution may only work starting with Python 3.7.